# Django Admin Interface overlapping

Tags: css, django

I have a standard Django admin site. The description overlap the input widget. How can i fix that? Is this a bug in Django or my fault?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/krDgt.png]

Comment: I tried it with Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit and increase the white spaces. You can the relevant CSS files in

```
"site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css"
```

**[UPDATE]:**

You can just enhance it for this page only using  custom templates.

{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

```
{% block extrastyle %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <style type="text/css">

    .aligned label {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 10px 0 0;
        float: left;
        width: 20em; /* updated */
    }
      </style>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Then I must in every installation of the software manipulate Django?

Comment: No. You can add this html as part of a "custom admin media". Please refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options